# If there is infinite solutions to a linear system, shouldn't the planes be on top of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to couple the solution of a linear system, to the graphical version, and understand why it looks as it does

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 15 & 10 \\
    0 & 1 & -5 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

The solution looks like so:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}  \\
    x_{2}  \\
    x_{3}  \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    10-15t  \\
    5t-3  \\
    t  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So we have a free variable, which i suppose equals an infinite amount of solutions.
[image]

But with the graphical representation in 3d, it shows that the planes have different directions. I was just wondering how to think about this, is it the intersection line that is infinite?

Comment: Yes, one free variable, so the solution set is geometrically $1$-dimensional (i.e., a line).

Comment: You have some typos. It should be $10-15t$, not $10-15_t$. Similarly, it should be $5t-3$, not $5_t-3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But with the graphical representation in 3d, it shows that the planes have different directions. I was just wondering how to think about this, is it the intersection line that is infinite?

Think about this geometrically (take two pieces of paper and "do it"); two planes can:

1. be **parallel** but not co-inciding, then they have *no common points*;
2. be **co-inciding** (which is a special case of parallel, if you like), then *all points are common*;
3. when they're not parallel, they **intersect** in a line: all the *points of the line are common*.

Convince yourself that there are no other possibilities.

Algebraically, the systems corresponding to the situations above will have:

1. no solutions;
2. an infinite number of solutions with *two* free variables (a parametrization of the plane!);
3. an infinite number of solutions with *one* free variables (a parametrization of the line).

You're in situation 3: an infinite number of solutions, but that doesn't mean the planes coincide.